# Excel - Replicating a SUMPRODUCT formula with already summed up values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, sumproduct

I have a sheet that uses the below formula to arrive at a figure:

`=SUMPRODUCT(E12:K12,E23:K23)/M10`

To my understanding, it's getting the sum of E12:K12(593+622+636+620+595+583+589) and multiplying that together with the sum of E23:K23(5740+5160+5432+4640+4716+7372+6696); then dividing the result by M10(39,756).

I have 2 new cells that contain the results of the two summed ranges but when I try to replicate the formula with a regular sum, the result is different:

`=SUM(IntradayPlan2!D346*IntradayPlan2!D347)/P12`

The result should be 604 but it's coming out at 4383. P12 contains the same number as M10 and the 2 cells in the SUM are summing the same values as the original SUMPRODUCT formula is.

For clarity, I'm currently replicating the main sheet a second time to generate this result. It's slowing down the workbook and most of the other detail on the replicated sheet isn't needed, so I'm trying to get rid of it.

I'm sure I'm missing something when it comes to SUMPRODUCT but after an hour of Googling around I can't work it out. Is there a way of replicating the same maths procedure with my new totals instead?

Comment: Sumproduct basically multiplies the values in both the arrays and finally adds. First val from first array will get multiplied with first value from second array and so on. Then it finally adds the multiplied output.

Comment: You can replace SUMPRODUCT with SUM by using ranges and CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER. `=SUM( E12:K12 * E23:K23 )/M10`.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I think I'll have to use SUMPRODUCT in the end but reference a different couple of arrays. I wanted to avoid this but due to what SUMPRODUCT actually does (thanks for the great explanation @GowthamJayachandiran) I don't think I can get the same result using 2 total values instead. I guess that's why SUMPRODUCT exists!

Answer (score 0):

After the great explanation by Gowtham I don't think it's possible to recreate the result of a SUMPRODUCT by using total values of the 2 used arrays.

Those cells actually get their values from another sheet, which I need to keep anyway. So I've created a couple of new rows which puts those figures in a line (their otherwise spread out across the sheet) and have referenced those new groups instead.

`=SUMPRODUCT(IntradayPlan2!D355:J355,IntradayPlan2!D356:J356)/O12`

And I'm getting the expected result :)